# select query to limit no. of columns and rows mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table named `city_map`. I want to display only the given fields in the snapshot in red rectangale.

Suppose the `sl_no` is given as 1 to 4, how do I get the required output?

[image: Screenshot of table output]

I am trying with this query:

```
select * from city_map where sl_no between 1 and 4
```

And I'm getting the first 4 rows but I only want to display the columns `Hyderabad`, `Itanagar`, `Dispur` and `Patna`.

Comment: That is not a table (in a RDBMS sense). See normalization.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
select sl_no,capital,Hyderabad,Itanagar,Dispur,Patna from city_map where sl_no between 1 and 4
```

Comment: but the problem is that the value 1 and 4 will be given by the user through the interface created in jave. so i need a dynamic query.

Comment: i dont know about java, but if like that you must get value of capital do user want on java as string after that you can replace `select sl_no,capital,Hyderabad,Itanagar,Dispur,Patna` part with `select sl_no,capital,:variablecapitaldouserwant`

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable names in the query and pass the value from method as query parameter,

```
SELECT sl_no,capital,Hyderabad,Itanagar,Dispur,Patna 
FROM city_map WHERE sl_no BETWEEN :slNoFrom AND :slNoTo ORDER BY sl_no
```

try using String.format as,

```
String.format(yourQuery,
 NEW Object[]{ColumnName1,ColumnName2,ColumnName3,ColumnName4,ColumnName5}
```

and use %s as a placeholder in a query,

```
 SELECT sl_no,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s
 FROM city_map WHERE sl_no BETWEEN :slNoFrom AND :slNoTo ORDER BY sl_no
```

Comment: but the problem is that the value 1 and 4 will be given by the user through the interface created in jave. so i need a dynamic query.

Comment: @JahangirAlam I have updated the query which will take dynamic sl_no.

Comment: dynamic sl_no i can also give but my problem is with dynamic columns, how to set dynamic columns in select statement

Comment: @JahangirAlam I have edited my answer, but its better to select all columns in select query and from the result set you can get specific column value..

Comment: will this query run at java lang.

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple query :

```
select sl_no,capital,Hyderabad,Itanagar,Dispur,Patna from city_map where sl_no between 1 and 4
```